# Reverting after git bisect

Tags: git, git-revert, git-bisect

*I'm doing a calculator project. In that, I've to find the bad commit using the **git bisect** and remove that commit using **git revert**. The resultant has to be staged, commit and pushed to the remote repo.*

Using git bisect, I found the bad commit.

Then typed, **git bisect reset**

Later, I used **git revert commitSHA**

Shows some message to resolve conflicts.
Visited the file(newfile.py), and removed the statements which caused that.
Then staged it with **git add .**
Then, 
       **git commit** 
and used the revert message as mentioned.

Used, **git push**

After I do all these things, it's still showing like it's not complete.

Since I'm a beginner, I would like to know whether I missed something in between or this is not the way.
Help me out!

Comment: All commands look good. What is "*still showing like it's not complete*"?

Comment: Like the changes which we expect after revert is not showing. Showing failed test case

Comment: "*Visited the file(newfile.py), and removed the statements which caused*" conflict — this, may be?

Comment: I resolved the conflict by removing the statements which are inside the <<<<HEAD...........

Comment: But the bad commit was meant tbe used to change the variable a's value from 20 to 10

Comment: I also facing same issue could you suggest me heedful steps

Answer (score 0):

After you have found the bad commit
run `git bisect reset`

After that run

```
git revert #SHA
```

You should not see any conflicts.

```
:wq
```

then

```
git push
```